# How to get div value when id of div is created in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Please tell me solution of this problem.
I am creating 5 dynamic `div`s and their `id`s using a for loop. I want to get the the loop counter value and each of the created `div`'s html in the format **"counter: html"** like `1:123`. Right now I am getting only the loop counter value.

```
<html>
<div id="feed"></div>

</html>
<script>
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '" value='
      123 '/>');



    var abc = $("#news" + i).attr("value");
    console.log(abc);
  }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share complete code. it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want to get the value of div i.e 123. but it is not static value. the value is coming from json api and I am appending that value in value attribute of div. so I have to display value of div.

Comment: The syntax is wrong for the line where you create the div, so that won't run at all.

Comment: Change the line to `$('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '" value=' +
      123 + '/>');` (note the added `+`'es)

Comment: `<div>` has no `value`, use a `data-` attribute

Answer (score 0):

updating the answer as per the updated question. This code will work for you. Give it a try.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '">'+ i +': Test</div>');
}
```

But I tell you again not to use the value tag, you already have your counter in id so split it fro there if you want.

[image]

Cheers!!

Comment: Actually value attributes contains dynamic value. i.e. each div contains different value.

Comment: @MohammadIqbal no, each div contains different *html*, it's an important distinction

Comment: so what i have to do when i have to display 200 data that are coming from json api

Comment: @MohammadIqbal  if you want to display it, use html tag, else explaint what youi want to do with data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `id`s use a `class`
2. `'<div id="news' + i + '" value='123'/>'` should be `'<div class="news">123</div>'`
3. Use `.html()` not `.attr("value")`

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  $('#feed').append('<div class="news">123</div>');

  var abc = $('.news').eq(i).html(); // gets the html of the div with the class "news" at the index supplied by `i`, keep in mind that arrays are 0 based so 0 is the first, 1 is the second....
  console.log((i+1)+':'+abc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feed"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but when i m using your code it display in console like this. 5 undefined. means counter of for loop

Comment: @MohammadIqbal It works on my end, as shown in the screenshot, can you show me how you are using it?

Comment: But @DelightedD0D I have to also increment the div id

Comment: Yes, but saying that incrementing the div ids is a bad way to do this. It can be done, sure. But a better way to do it is to use a class. This is exactly the kind of thing that classes are for.

Comment: Give them a class instead of ids like shown here. `$('.news')` will create an array of all elements with the class `news` and you can access any of them you want by calling `$('.news').eq(i)` where `i` is the index of of the element you want from that array

Comment: but @DelightedD0D I need the output like this:
1:123
2:123
3:123

Comment: I have not to append multiple value on a single div. I have to display each value in a different div that's why I am creating multiple div and assigning multiple id on each div.

Comment: @MohammadIqbal a div can only have one `id` attribute

Comment: @MohammadIqbal As far as the `1:123 ` format, I edited the above to show you how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '" value="123"></div>');

    //and I want to get the value of dynamic created div using this code but I am getting only the loop counter value. Please help me to get this answer.

    var abc = $("#news" + i).attr('value');
    console.log(abc + " : " + i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div id="feed"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: this code snippet will producing following output:
undefined : 1
undefined : 2
undefined : 3
undefined : 4
undefined : 5

Comment: I could see 123 : 1
123 : 2
123 : 3
123 : 4
123 : 5 in the Google Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet doesn't even work for me, this however, does:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
$('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '" value="123"/>');
var abc = $("#news" + i).attr("value");
console.log(abc);}
```

I simply changed the single quotes of value='123' to double quotes: value="123".

Answer (score -1):

You're using `id`'s. You can't use an `id` on multiple `divs`, so you need to use `class`.

Comment: This should be a comment, or should be elaborated on to be considered an answer

Comment: For loop variable `i` is being appended to the `id`.. So id will be unique.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what you want, and `div` tag not supposed have value attribute, if you want to add your defined attribute use `data-my_attribute` instead. In your code, everything is ok except for this code :

**Change this :**

```
$('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '" value='123'></div>');
```

**into this :**

```
$('#feed').append('<div id="news' + i + '" value="123"></div>');
```

Comment: `'<div id="news' + i + '" value="123"/>'` is not valid and this does not address the other issues with the OP's code

Comment: What you mean not valid, i know the `value` attribute declaration is not valid, but the only wrong for that code is this part. The console.log(abc) he made will output the value from attribute of value.

Comment: I mean this is not valid html, please see http://prntscr.com/6x591n it should be `'<div id="news' + i + '">123</div>'` while some browsers may compensate for "html soup" like this, it will not work reliably across platforms and will break the page layout in many cases

Comment: Yes i'm aware that. and i know it not valid, and already mentioned on my post, but it depend on @Mohammad Iqbal what he want and why. Maybe he doing that for a reason, otherwise he did't know how to code that. If so, then my mistake. Cheers.

Comment: See what I want to say @Norlihazmey Ghazali:
I have a json api that contain multiple list of data such as- 
data[
         id:1234
         name:xyz
       ]
this is more than 200  array data.
Now i have to display that data in a page.
 for that I am creating div using for loop and assigning div id also

Comment: then you want the id value react as a value in Value Attribute, or what??

Comment: i want the value data for passing as a parameter

Comment: i see a lot of answered answering your question including mine, is it not solved yet??